# Как поставить width в процентах для старых браузеров?

Tags: css

А именно для IE хотябы от 8 и выше. Нигде точной инфы нету или это сказывается моя бессоница. Ширина меняется только если поставить какую-нить фиксированную ширину

кусочки кода

```
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:37.1%;
height:100%;
text-align:left;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.47);
color:#fff;         
padding-left:3.6%;
padding-right:3%;
padding-top:8%;
```

Comment: поставил отдельные стили для IE

     <!--[if lte IE 10]><link href="css/style_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /<![endif]--> 

теперь вроде разобрался, подгоняю под нужные размеры, но там неудобная проблема, теперь чтобы написать padding-top мне надо писать padding-bottom, ибо они начали работать наоборот тоже самое и с margin.

Comment: для IE10 условные комментарии не работают